# What happens to child process once the shell command is completed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd, exec

So i am using exec to open a shell and run a shell command for me which is:

```
exec('del filename & exit')
```

Using exit to close the Shell

I have to use this exec multiple times in a single run, i have not been able to find what happens to the child process once it goes to exit and closes the CMD, does the child process close itself as soon as the command is completed or do i have to explicitly close the child process

Comment: `del filename & exit` looks like a *Windows Command Processor* command line. There is executed in this case `%ComSpec% /c del filename & exit` which expands to `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c del filename & exit`. Open a command prompt window, run `cmd /?` and read the output usage help explaining how the arguments after option `/C` are interpreted by `cmd` depending on various criteria. The option `/c` instructs `cmd` to execute the command line and then close itself. `& exit` is completely unnecessary for that reason. The file in the current directory is deleted if possible by `cmd`.

Comment: If the *Node.js* script itself does not determine which directory is the current directory, then the process starting `node.exe` for interpreting the *Node.js* script defines the current working directory on calling the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) for execution of `node.exe` with the *Node.js* script file name as argument. Any directory can be therefore the current directory on `node.exe` calling `CreateProcess` to run `cmd.exe` with the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

**UNIX `exec` (POSIX system call)**

There is no child process involved in the picture.

Per the [linux man pages](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html),

> One sometimes sees execve() (and the related functions described
> in exec(3)) described as "executing a new process" (or similar).
> This is a highly misleading description: **there is no new process;
> many attributes of the calling process remain unchanged (in
> particular, its PID).  All that execve() does is arrange for an
> existing process (the calling process) to execute a new program.**

Instead, the `exec()` family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image. [see: man pages](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html)

---

---

**Node.js `exec` (Child process module)**

Unlike the POSIX exec, this function DOES spawn a new process.

Per the [docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v20.x/api/child_process.html#child_processexeccommand-options-callback),

> Unlike the exec(3) POSIX system call, child_process.exec() **does not replace the existing process** and uses a shell to execute the command.

To answer your question,

> does the child process close itself as soon as the command is completed or do i have to explicitly close the child process

The child process is expected to be terminated automatically by the `ChildProcess` instance, but there is **no guarantee** that the process will terminate at all costs.

Per docs, several events are emitted upon resolution of a child process,

1. [Event '`exit`':](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v20.x/api/child_process.html#event-exit)

When the 'exit' event is triggered, child process stdio streams might still be open.

```
child.on('exit', (code) => {
   console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

Note that, the 'exit' event may or may not fire after an error has occurred. When listening to both the 'exit' and 'error' events, guard against accidentally invoking handler functions multiple times.

---

2. [Event '`error`':](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v20.x/api/child_process.html#event-error)

The 'error' event is emitted whenever:

- The process could not be spawned.
- The process could not be killed.
- Sending a message to the child process failed.
- The child process was aborted via the signal option.

```
child.on('error', (err) => {
// This will be called with err being an AbortError if the controller aborts
});
```

---

3. [Event '`close`':](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v20.x/api/child_process.html#event-close)

The 'close' event is emitted after a process has ended and the stdio streams of a child process have been closed. This is distinct from the 'exit' event, since multiple processes might share the same stdio streams. The 'close' event will always emit after 'exit' was already emitted, or 'error' if the child failed to spawn.

---

Additionally, a timeout option and a killSignal can be specified to a process for it to be killed by the Node.js runtime using the specified signal if it does not exit in the specified timeout period.

If timeout is greater than 0, the parent will send the signal identified by the killSignal property (the default is 'SIGTERM') if the child runs longer than timeout milliseconds.

You can pass these options as the 2nd parameter to the `exec` method as follows:

```
child_process.exec('del filename', {
   timeout: 1000, //milliseconds
   killSignal: "SIGINT"  //POSIX signal name
});
```

Final note on these handlers:

> Node.js establishes signal handlers for SIGINT and SIGTERM and **Node.js processes will not terminate immediately due to receipt of those signals.** Rather, Node.js will perform a sequence of cleanup actions and then will re-raise the handled signal.

Comment: While the man page is `exec(3)` there is no Unix/POSIX call named exactly `exec` (as shown at your second link) and moreover no Unix/POSIX call handles the argument shown in the Q. And the Q is tagged nodejs -- so it is clearly about the `exec` function in [**the `child_process` module of nodejs**](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v20.x/api/child_process.html#child_processexeccommand-options-callback) which DOES create a child process -- like fork PLUS execX or posix_spawnX on Unix/POSIX, but different on Windows which I'm pretty sure is the Q.

Comment: You are right. I jumped right into the question and clearly have omitted the tags! Funny that neither the question nor the title doesn't mention anything about node.js environment, which clearly what the "Q" is about. In that case, I would be happy if you can update the answer or create a new one, which in that case I will remove mine. --Thanks